# How to use tikzpicture/tkiz with IEEE access format?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, ieeetran

I have a **tikzpicture** that works fine in **IEEE format**. But when I copy the same code to **IEEE access format**, I got many errors. I googled for how to use TKIZ in IEEE access, but these solutions does not work.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to stack exchange, what do you mean WME ??

Comment: MWE stands for minimal working (or not working) example. Follow the link I posted for an explanation. But unless you show code that produces the "many errors" and explain why the solutions you tried "don't work", no one can help because we are just guessing what is wrong. You need to post a complete document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which contains just enough code to reproduce your errors.

Comment: Worst case, put the tikzpicture into a standalone and include the resulting PDF in your document.